# How to write an upsert trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

In PostgreSQL 9.6 and later, what is the correct way to define a trigger function that will perform an
update whenever an insert would fail because of a uniqueness constraint?

I know it is straightforward to write `insert ... on conflict ... do update set ...` statements, but my
idea is that I want to have some tables that treat repeated inserts as updates; otherwise that piece
of logic would have to be taken care of by the application, not the DB.

One solution that I have found and that superficially does work is this:

```
create table versions (
  key           text primary key,
  version       text );

/* ### TAINT not sure whether there may be race conditions with this upsert trigger */
create function on_before_insert_versions() returns trigger language plpgsql volatile as $$ begin
  if exists ( select 1 from versions where key = new.key ) then
    update versions set version = new.version where key = new.key;
    return null;
    end if;
  return new;
  end; $$;

create trigger on_before_insert_versions
  before insert on versions for each row execute procedure on_before_insert_versions();

insert into versions values
  ( 'server', '3.0.3' ),
  ( 'api',    '2' );

insert into versions values
  ( 'api',    '3' );

select * from versions;

  key   | version 
--------+---------
 server | 3.0.3
 api    | 3
```

However, isn't the trigger prone to race conditions? I tried to use an 
`insert ... on conflict ... do update set ...` statement in the trigger, but that failed of course
because it triggers the trigger function itself, leading to infinite regress.

I also tried to use a pair of `alter table ... disable trigger ...` / `enable` statements, but that 
errors with `cannot ALTER TABLE ... because it is being used by active queries in this session`.

**What is the canonical form to always perform an update instead of an insert on uniqueness constraint
violation in PostgreSQL?**

**Update**—Upserts in PostgreSQL, or their long-time absence, are somehwat of a hot topic, and many not-so-perfect solutions are regularly suggested.

Given that the Postgres maintainers have taken so much time and care to make `insert ... on conflict .. do update` work without race conditions, it is perhaps unwise to embrace a homebrewed solution that 'seems to work' (until it doesn't).

When I wrote my question, I was adamant to have an `insert` trigger that does an `update` on conflict; this is not well supported by PostgreSQL, the chief problem being that the `insert` that you perform on the same table within a `before insert` trigger will cause that same trigger to be called. @Laurenz Albe suggested how to escape from the infinite loop, and while the proposed technique (ingenious!) looks like a good thing to remember, we do not know about possible impacts on performance or other side effects.

In then end, @Ilya Dyoshin hit the nail by proposing to just call a function from the application that wraps the necessary SQL logic. I feel this is a win/win solution because

1) it does not change the semantics of `insert into x` for table `x` to 'really mean `update`, sometimes';

2) the 'upsert semantics' are made explicit in the application code, but not spelled out in gory detail;

3) you can *still* do an `insert` without intending an implicit 'update'—in hindsight, this is perhaps the most important consideration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree with Ilya that it would be better to do this in the application in a straightforward way.

But I take it in the spirit of a thought experiment, and my solution uses the power of `pg_trigger_depth()` to escape endless recursion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_before_insert_versions() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF pg_trigger_depth() = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO versions (key, version) VALUES (NEW.key, NEW.version)
         ON CONFLICT (key)
         DO UPDATE SET version = NEW.version;
      RETURN NULL;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEW;
   END IF;
END;$$;
```

Your solution is definitely vulnerable to a race condition: two concurrent INSERTs can lead to concurrently running triggers, both of which cannot find a matching row in `versions` and consequently lead to an INSERT, one of which must fail.

Comment: I tried it (only superficially though, no concurrency) and your solution works. You say, "it would be better to do this in the application in a straightforward way"; care to explain why? I take it that at some point the application might have to take into account that in this table an `insert` may become an `update`, so there's a reason make the upsert explicit in the app. OTOH I could have written a trigger that inserts some extra data in some other table and in *that* case a plain `insert` emitted by the app with no mention of the other table would be considered OK, no?

Comment: Triggers are a performance hit, and I can see no advantage here. There is nothing unclean about the application being aware that it will perform an "upsert". Changing the behaviour of a table transparent to the application seems like a bad design (too cute). Sure, using a trigger for auditing or similar is fine - there is no change in the semantics of the INSERT in this case.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use pure upsert.

otherwise you can introduce more complicated logic and don't return the data for insert from the trigger (read the docs = if trigger before insert is not returning value no insert is performed)

Comment: Thanks for regarding this topic but 'read the docs' is not very helpful. I know how to write a before-insert trigger that inhibits insertion (shown above). The point is that if I use the `insert .. on conflict` syntax within the trigger function, that statement will in itself call the trigger, causing recursion.—Not sure what you mean with 'pure upsert'.

Comment: well, trigger in general should not perform insert in same specific table...  if you need to upsert - than just upsert - rewrite application from your pure insert statement to upsert from trigger and remove trigger - that will solve the problem.

Comment: if you don't want your application perform upsert calls (keep the logic in the database), than rework your trigger to SQL function and make your application call that function.  ` CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_versions(__key, __version) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE SQL AS
      INSERT INTO versions (key, version) VALUES (__key, __version)
         ON CONFLICT (key)
         DO UPDATE SET version = __version;`