# Why is Sequelize upsert not working with composite unique key?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use this table in a PostgreSQL database:

```sql
 create table if not exists "Service" (
    _id uuid not null primary key,
    service text not null,
    "count" integer not null,
    "date" timestamp with time zone,
    team uuid,
    organisation uuid,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
    unique (service, "date", organisation),
    foreign key ("team") references "Team"("_id"),
    foreign key ("organisation") references "Organisation"("_id")
);
```

When I try an `upsert` with `Sequelize` with the following code, it throws an error:

```js
Service.upsert({ team, date, service, organisation, count }, { returning: true })
```

Error is:

> error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Service_service_date_organisation_key"
>
> Key (service, date, organisation)= (xxx, 2022-12-30 01:00:00+01, 12345678-5f63-1bc6-3924-517713f97cc3) already exists.

But according to Sequelize documentation it should work: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/upgrade/#modelupsert

> Note for Postgres users: If upsert payload contains PK field, then PK will be used as the conflict target. Otherwise first unique constraint will be selected as the conflict key.

How can I find this duplicate key error and get it work with the composite unique key: `unique (service, "date", organisation)`?

Comment: *first unique constraint will be selected as the conflict key* - I wonder in what order. This could mean that if there's no PK in the payload but the PK happens to be the first unique constraint, it'll still target the PK. If constraints are selected based on the order of their names, you could rename the constraints so that yours comes first. If it skips the PK but there happens to be some other constraint that's picked before yours - [you can list them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987795/5298879) - you could just drop/recreate/rename that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is related to [issue #13240](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13240).

If you're on [Sequelize 6.12](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v6.12.0) or above, you should be able to use an explicit list of [`conflictFields`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/13723):

```js
Service.upsert(
    { team, date, service, organisation, count }, 
    { conflictFields: ["service", "date", "organisation"] },
    { returning: true }
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work with postgres if the `conflictFields` are not unique indexes, right?

Comment: That's right. There must be a constraint that the `insert` would violate, so that the violation is caught and handled with an `update` instead. The fields listed as `conflictFields` are used to guess what constraint you wish to handle based on what index uses them. In plain SQL you can also name the specific constraint directly. More on the `on conflict...do update` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). More on `constraints` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS).

Answer (score -1):

## References

Similar questions were asked on GitHub, see:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13240
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13412

and they were not solved so far, so, as the time of this writing, this issue seems to be unresolved, so you will need to work-around it. Below I will provide a few ideas to solve this, but since I have never worked with Sequelize, it is possible that I have some syntax error or some misunderstanding. If so, please point it out and I'll fix it.

## Approach 1: Querying by your unique key and inserting/updating by it

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    service: yourservice,
    date: yourdate,
    organization: yourorganization
  }
});
```

And then `insert` if the result is empty, update otherwise.

## Approach 2: Modifying your schema

Since your composite `unique` key is a candidate key, an option would be to remove your `_id` field and make your `(service, "date", organization)` unique.

## Approach 3: Implement an insert trigger on your table

You could simply call `insert` from Sequelize and let a PostgreSQL `trigger` handle the upserting, see: [How to write an upsert trigger in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562240/how-to-write-an-upsert-trigger-in-postgresql)

Example trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_before_insert_versions() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF pg_trigger_depth() = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO versions (key, version) VALUES (NEW.key, NEW.version)
         ON CONFLICT (key)
         DO UPDATE SET version = NEW.version;
      RETURN NULL;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEW;
   END IF;
END;$$;
```

You of course will need to change table and field names accordingly to your schema and command.